# JavaScript UTC Date

Tags: javascript

I try to get UTC Date. Why

```
(new Date("2015-04-22")).getUTCDate() = 22
```

And

```
(new Date("Apr 22, 2015")).getUTCDate() = 21
```

?

Comment: I get the result of `22`

Comment: try this one: Date.UTC(2015-04-22);

Comment: Depend of the local time, see : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcdate.asp

Comment: @InformatikBabo You want to check `1989`?

Comment: @R3tep but I'm using the same dates

Comment: @user3629171 No, I think `2015-04-22` is an universal format. But `Apr 22, 2015` is a local format.

Comment: Odd, it seems that `"2015-04-22"` for me resolves to 01:00. But `"Apr 22, 2015"` resolves to 00:00. Being UTC+1 myself, this resolves to 23:00 and 00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote MDN on the workings of `Date.parse` (called by `new Date("string")`):

> ### [Differences in assumed time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time-zone)
>
> Given a date string of `"March 7, 2014"`, `parse()` assumes a local time zone, but given an ISO format such as `"2014-03-07"` it will assume
>   a time zone of UTC. Therefore Date objects produced using those
>   strings will represent different moments in time unless the system is
>   set with a local time zone of UTC. This means that two date strings
>   that appear equivalent may result in two different values depending on
>   the format of the string that is being converted **(this behavior is
>   changed in ECMAScript ed 6 so that both will be treated as local)**.

Watch out for the warning I've highlighted on the last line

Comment: Indeed, I was about to quote this from MDN *dateString
A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).*